# Error connecting to SQL Azure database from on premise server "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server."

Tags: powershell

When I try to establish connection to SQL Azure database using windows authentication from on premise server received error message "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server."

PowerShell establish connection to SQL Azure database:

```
$SQLSERVER = 'ServerName.database.windows.net';
$SQLDB = 'TestDB';
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$SQLDB;Integrated Security=True";
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
$SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
```

Error message:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server."
At line:7 char:1
+ $SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Answer (score 1):

'Integrated Security' in connection string is not supported for Azure windows authentication, which caused this error. I have used below connection string to establish
connection to Azure SQL database using windows authentication (Authentication=Active Directory Integrated) fixed this issue.

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString ="Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$SQLDB;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
```

Refer this blog for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt761729(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but this can help others too. You need to set Integrated Security to False. Add this to your connection string:

> Integrated Security=False; Encrypt=True;

So your connection string becomes

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$SQLDB;Integrated Security=False";Encrypt=True;
```

Hope this helps.